# How to open/operate file in batch classes?

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, readfile, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have to import in a Table from file (csv for example).
I used this code:

```
public void run ()
{ 
    TextIO textIO;

    str filename, fileOpen, folder;
    int handle;
    Io thisMYFile;
    FileIoPermission perm;

    #File
    #avifiles
    #OCCRetryCount

    [handle, filename]  =   WINAPI::findFirstFile(folder + "\\*.csv");

    fileOpen = strFmt (folder + "\\" +  filename);

    perm = new FileIoPermission(fileOpen, 'w');
    perm.assert();

    thisMYFile = new CommaTextIo(fileOpen , 'w');
}
```

But in Debug the *class* `IO` *thisMYFile* is *null* and so I can't to read and get information.

In my `class declaration` I extends **RunBaseBarch**.

If I used a "normal" classes (not batch) I can read,write,move file etc, but now I can't to open.

I know the `WinAPI` classes not work in Batch, now I think there is also another way to read/open file in batch? With `WinAPIServer`class I can *findFirstFile* ?
A clarification, I have also a same problem if I don't schedule the process batch : flag *Batch processing* is **false**, in the batch dialog, and clicked only Ok. (example image)

[image: example image]

If you've a tutorial, any advice or help,

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Comment: the 'folder' is never assigned a value so you are looking for a file in \? Is that correct?

Comment: Can you give examples kindly? Very thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware that the batch runs on an other machine, the AOS will not have access to your local files.
Therefore always use a full [UNC file path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) to the file, ex. \\MyHost\Temp\x.csv

If `new CommaTextIO` fails to open the file, it returns `null`, it does not throw an exception. If you do not test for `null` your code will fail later.

Comment: Also, if not operating on your own server, folder permissions. 90% of my troubleshooting relating to *io -imports/exports are related to changed folder permissions on customer environment.

Comment: can you explain with some kind of example, please?very kind!

Comment: Hi @Jan B. Kjeldsen nice way.